# Calculate monthly efficiency in power pivot

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, calculation

I am very new to this power pivot and dax Commands ,kindly help me out here

my sample table looks like this :
[image: Sample Table]

Now to calculate monthly efficiency i need to make a measure which satisfies below criteria:

```
Sum the efficiency for each distinct date & divide by the count of distinct dates for the month
```

so far for days my below formula is working , but when i group the date into month it is only showing the sum, so kindly help me how to achieve this ;

```
Actual Efficiency CL2:=CALCULATE(SUM(CL1[Day Wise Efficiency]),DISTINCT(CL1[Date (dd/mm/yy)]))
```

[image: Day wise result]

[image: Monthly result showing the sum where i need the total sum divided count of distinct day in dates column for the month]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide part is not in your formula, below DAX might help:

```
Actual Efficiency CL2 :=
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( CL1[Day Wise Efficiency] ) ),
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCT ( CL1[Date (dd/mm/yy)] ) )
)
```

Note that `DISTINCT ( CL1[Date (dd/mm/yy)] )` is not required in the sum as dates in rows will be unique.
To Divide the sum at month level `DISTINCT ( CL1[Date (dd/mm/yy)] )` is required as we need how many days a month has.
At day level there will always be 1 to divide by.

Thanks